# explanation function with parameter e

Tags: javascript

I have this function copied from an exercise that I am trying to understand

```
loadEventListeners();

function loadEventListeners () {
  cursos.addEventListener('click', addToCart);
}

function addToCart(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.classList);
}
```

I don't understand why it assigns the parameter "e" and then invokes it through e.target or because the `preventDefault()` is used

what the function does is return the list of classes on the button you click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` represents `Event` intefrace. The Event interface represents an event that takes place in the DOM. An event can be triggered by the user action e.g. clicking the mouse button or tapping keyboard.

Your function `addToCart()` triggered by user action, and `e` contains information about this event.

The `preventDefault()` method "cancels" the event, meaning that the default action that belongs to the event will not occur. For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL.

Read more about the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) and [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever any event is triggered, a call function is called. In which event object is passed.

Event object contains every information related to event. Like on which button it is click, axis, attributes.

You can use this function for many purposes like finding parents, child, dimensions of the element and much more.

There are two function `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` both used for different purposes.

preventDefault cancle default action that belongs to element like anchor element or so.

The `stopPropagation()` method prevents propagation of the same event from being called to child/ parents.